# lm(): loop through multiple linear models exporting p-value of F-statistic

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a large data set for which I need to run a linear model comparing groups. 
I need to find the p-values for group comparisons using a linear model. There are four groups (so I need 1~2, 1~3. 1~4, 2~3, 2~4, 3~4) and and there are 130 columns for which the data from these groups needs to be compared. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I have this, which gives me exactly what I need.

```
fit<-lm(variable~group, data=data)
summary(fit)
```

However, with all of the groups and columns, I have nearly 800 comparisons to make, so I want to avoid doing this manually. I tried writing a for loop, but it isn't working.

```
k<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:130){
 [i,1]<-colnames(data)
 fit<- lm(i~group, data=data)
 [i,2] <- fit$p.value
}
```

But this has given me a variety of different errors. I really just need the p-values. Help would be greatly greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a sample of what your data looks like? i.e. the structure. That would make it easier to assist you.

Comment: The data has one column with a group number (e.g., each row has a 0, 1, 2, or 3 in the first column); these are the groups to be compared. Then each subsequent column has a particular factor I'm interested in with values. I want to compare groups within each column individually. I used read.csv to import the data and then head(data), string(data). Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2016-06-18) Your question is **not completely answerable** at this stage. In the following, I shall point out several problems.

---

**How to get p-value properly**

I assume you want p-value of F-statistic for the model, as an indication of goodness of fit. Suppose your fitted model is `fit`, we should do this way:

```
fstatistic <- summary(fit)$fstatistic
p_value <- unname(1 - pf(fstatistic[1], fstatistic[2], fstatistic[3]))
```

As an example, I will use built-in dataset `trees` as an demonstration.

```
fit <- lm(Height ~ Girth, trees)
## truncated output of summary(fit)
# > summary(fit)
# Residual standard error: 5.538 on 29 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.2697,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.2445 
F-statistic: 10.71 on 1 and 29 DF,  p-value: 0.002758

fstatistic <- summary(fit)$fstatistic
p_value <- unname(1 - pf(fstatistic[1], fstatistic[2], fstatistic[3]))
## > p_value
# [1] 0.002757815
```

So, `p_value` agrees with the printed summary.

---

**Your loop**

I suggest you use vectors rather than data frame during computation/update.

```
variable <- character(130)
p.value <- numeric(130)
```

You can combine the results at the end to a data frame via:

```
k <- data.frame(var = variable, p.value = p.value)
```

Why? Because this is memory efficient! Now, after those correction, we arrive at:

```
variable <- character(130)
p.value <- numeric(130)
for (i in 1:130) {
  variable[i] <- colnames(data)
  fit <- lm(i~group, data=data)
  fstatistic <- summary(fit)$fstatistic
  p_value <- unname(1 - pf(fstatistic[1], fstatistic[2], fstatistic[3]))
  p.value[i] <- p_value
  }
k <- data.frame(var = variable, p.value = p.value)
```

---

**Further problems**

I still don't think the above code above will work. Because I am not sure whether the following is doing correct:

```
  variable[i] <- colnames(data)
  fit <- lm(i~group, data=data)
```

1. During the loop, `data` is not changed, so `colnames(data)` returns a vector, hence `var[i] <- colnames(data)` will trigger error.
2. `i~group` looks odd. Do you have `i` in your `data`?

I can't help you solve these issues. I have no idea of what your `data` looks like. But if you could put in a subset of your data, it would be OK.

---

**Follow-up** (2016-06-19)

> Thank you. This has been extremely helpful. I don't have "i" in my data, but I was hoping that I could use that to represent the different column names, so that it goes through all of them. Is there a way to assign column names numbers so that this would work?

Yes, but I need to know what you have for each column.

> Column 1 has a group number. The following columns have data for different factors I am looking at.

OK, so I think `ncol(data) = 131`, where the first column is `group`, and the remaining 130 columns are what you will test. Then this should work:

```
variable <- colnames(data)[-1]
p.value <- numeric(130)
for (i in 1:130) {
  fit <- lm(paste(variable[i], "group", sep = "~"), data=data)
  fstatistic <- summary(fit)$fstatistic
  p_value <- unname(1 - pf(fstatistic[1], fstatistic[2], fstatistic[3]))
  p.value[i] <- p_value
  }
k <- data.frame(var = variable, p.value = p.value)
```

It is possible to use `sapply()` instead of the above *for* loop. But I think there is no performance difference, as loop overhead is so much tiny compared with `lm()` and `summary()`.

Comment: Thank you. This has been extremely helpful. I don't have "i" in my data, but I was hoping that I could use that to represent the different column names, so that it goes through all of them. Is there a way to assign column names numbers so that this would work? Unfortunately, I cannot upload my data, as it is on my work computer, and I am not allowed to share it. I can try to better explain what it looks like though in the next comment:

Comment: Column 1 has a group number (e.g., 0, 1, 2, or 3, depending on the participants classification). The following columns have data for different factors I am looking at (e.g. brain grey matter decay rates for a specific location). I then want to go through each column and basically do an ANOVA comparing the four groups. I thought a loop would be the best way to do this, since it is the same test just in hundreds of columns. Each row is for a participant, with their group classification and their decay rate for that particular region. Does this help at all?

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think this can get you started at least. It uses the dplyr and broom packages. The basic idea is to define all the formulas you want as characters then use `lapply()` to run them through `lm()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

# Generate a vector of wanted formulas
forms <- c("mpg ~ cyl", "mpg ~ wt")

# Function to apply formula
lmit <- function(form){
  tidy(lm(as.formula(form), mtcars)) %>% 
    mutate(formula = form)
}

# Apply it and bind into a dataframe
results <- bind_rows(lapply(forms, lmit))
```